# Troubles with parallel processes in IRB on Mac

Tags: ruby, multithreading, macos, stdout, irb

I am working with a database via IRB, and I would like to make periodic changes in the database (e.g., every 10 sec) showing the log in STDOUT.

Also, I would like to have manual control being able to change the database and to stop the first process.

So far I came up to the following

```
def start
  stop
  @running = Thread.new do
    loop do
      fork do
        puts 'change the database'
      end
      sleep 10
    end
  end
  nil
end

def stop
  @running.kill if @running
end
```

However, this is not running every 10 sec unless I enter something in the main IRB thread.

How to make it working?

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `fork` and threads at the same time.

Comment: It was the only way to get output from the first process. Just thread doesn't produce stable output, while just fork is hard to control (if I am correct). Something is probably wrong in my setup and I have no idea how to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of readline on OSX are blocking. If one experiences the behavior you described, they can disable readline by putting

```
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = false
```

in .irbrc

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me (tested in irb with ruby 1.9.2-p180 and 1.8.7-p334).

Comment: Does it show the message every 10 sec and you do not press Enter?

Comment: Yes, every 10 secs and no need to press enter.

Comment: I get only the first message and have to press enter in order to get the next one and to continue the loop. I use ruby `1.9.2-p180` and irb `0.9.6` on Mac. Are you running Linux? Could you try to run IRB without `.irbrc`?

Comment: I'm running ubuntu lucid on a samsung nc10. Same effect (works) when running in `irb -f`. irb version is also `0.9.6`.

Comment: You could try to remove the fork (and just run it in the same process).

Comment: I had to add fork in order to make it somehow working. Things are worse without it - even if I enter something the output is delayed.